# Windows form actions like close through custom user control code?

Tags: vb.net

I have made a title bar (custom user control) that contains five controls. They are all labels but each one do different "job".

For example, one of them is an exit form button. If I put a `click` event into my custom user control's code, for example...

```
Private Sub ExitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
    Close()
End Sub
```

I get this error...

```
BC30451 'Close' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

On the other hand I can't put it into my project's code cause it can't find `ExitButton` as "isolated" control and do `close()`.

Any suggestions? I also want to do the same thing with minimize, maximize etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me guess; your button is in the user control. You try to call `Close()` on the `UserControl` class, which obviously is not a window and does not have it.

There are three solutions:

- Use the `ParentForm` property and call `Close()` on it (e.g. `ParentForm.Close()`). Easy but not too flexible; if you want to do other things than those which are implemented in the `Form` base class (like `Close()`), e.g. specific to the main form, you would have to cast it first and check if it's really the form you thought of. Also, all those things would need to be exposed with `Public` or `Internal`, don't expose what you don't have to expose.
- You pass the `Form` to the `UserControl`. Horrible because passing stuff around just ends up in spaghetti code.
- Better, raise an event by the `UserControl` which you handle in the form the `UserControl` is on. That's probably the most flexible approach.

Here's a small code example solving this with an event:

Open the code of the `UserControl` and add an event signature and raise that event when you click the button:

```
Public Class MyUserControl

    Public Event ButtonClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Private Sub MyButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyButton.Click
        RaiseEvent ButtonClicked(sender, e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then, in your `Form`, attach to the ButtonClicked event of the `UserControl`:

```
Public Class MyForm

    Private Sub MyUserControl1_ButtonClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyUserControl1.ButtonClicked
        Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

If you re-use the event for multiple buttons, you can check which button it is through the `sender` passed to the event. (Of course this can be optimized by just passing a casted `Button` instance as the event parameter, this is just a simple example).

Comment: Yes you are 100% in!!! What I am looking for is how I can "make" my user control's buttons do things into a form.

Any simple example on to raise an event from user control?

Comment: Sure, let me refresh my VB.NET syntax knowledge and write some event handling code, moment...

Comment: I wrote some sample code; if you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: When I add the first part of code I get this error... `BC30506 Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.`

Comment: I guess that happened because we added an event later on. The problem is that the user control is not declared with VB.NET's dumb `WithEvents` in the designer code. I guess you can fix it by going to the events tab of the `UserControl` in the property editor and double click the `ButtonClicked` event appearing there (make sure to successfully compile first without the code causing the error, or it won't appear in the list).

Comment: Done!!! Using third way of course. Thank you very much my friend, you are a Master!!! :)

Comment: Please take a look at my own answer... Do you believe this should be the correct answer? I don't mean that yours is wrong but I thing this is closer to what I was initially looking for... What do you think?

Comment: @Simonetos: That's the solution I already mentioned under bullet 1. I do not recommend it in case you want to call a custom method of your form, like `DoStuff()`.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get "close" from? You exit an application with application.exit()

Comment: I want to close a form not the whole application!!!! And I want to do the same thing with form maximize, minimize etc.

Comment: The answer also is not fully correct, applications are normally exited by closing the main form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close Application you can use:
Application.Exit()
If you want to close Form:
Me.Close()

Answer (score -1):

To close the form you use me.

me.close

Comment: That does not make a difference. Calling `Close()` like in the example above implicitly calls it on `Me`. The problem is that `Me` is not the Form.

Comment: Yeah, because you use it in a method inside a class inheriting from `Form`; e.g., like a button event handler where the button is on a `Form`; it is not on a `Form` in this question, so we do not have that method.

Comment: Than he needs to provide a public method in the form that performs the close and call that.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example?

Comment: @Rabtok: Then he also needs to pass the form to the user control; he can actually access it via `.Parent`, but that stops working when he somewhen moves the `UserControl` into another container (I'm not sure if there was `.ParentForm` or something, but I never liked that approach anyway).